# Access a web server which is running on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) from the local network

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, webserver, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After installing [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) as [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) (Windows Subsystem for Linux), I've run (as root):

```
cd ~
python3 -m http.server
```

Output:

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

And I tried to access to this web server from my windows machine, `http://0.0.0.0:8000` or `http://192.168.1.178:8000`, but without any success. The web server is available only by the address `http://127.0.0.1:8000` or `http://localhost:8000`. It means that I can't connect to this web server from another PC in my network. Is it possible to get access to WSL from the outside?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.nextofwindows.com/allow-server-running-inside-wsl-to-be-accessible-outside-windows-10-host) can help you.

Comment: Thanks for help but server still available through the localhost only. And no ability to connect from another PC to this server.

Comment: This was actually helpful for working on a single machine :)

Answer (score 39):

In your VM, execute `ifconfig`.

You will see your IP address in the first section (eth0:) inet x.x.x.x

This x.x.x.x is the IP address you have to put in your browser.

Comment: This is the answer. Works for WSL2 and does not need any firewall magic.

Comment: Hasn't [`ifconfig` been ***deprecated*** on Ubuntu/Linux](https://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/) for more than 10 years? Replaced by [`ip a`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2), `ip link`, and `ip -s`?

Answer (score 38):

None of the existing answers work for me, as WSL2 is running in its own VM and has its own network adapter. You need some sort of bridge or port forwarding for non-localhost requests to work (i.e. from another host on the same network).

I found a script in https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150 that worked to resolve the issue:

```
$remoteport = bash.exe -c "ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet '"
$found = $remoteport -match '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}';

if( $found ){
  $remoteport = $matches[0];
} else{
  echo "The Script Exited, the ip address of WSL 2 cannot be found";
  exit;
}

#[Ports]

#All the ports you want to forward separated by coma
$ports=@(80,443,10000,3000,5000);


#[Static ip]
#You can change the addr to your ip config to listen to a specific address
$addr='0.0.0.0';
$ports_a = $ports -join ",";


#Remove Firewall Exception Rules
iex "Remove-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName 'WSL 2 Firewall Unlock' ";

#adding Exception Rules for inbound and outbound Rules
iex "New-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName 'WSL 2 Firewall Unlock' -Direction Outbound -LocalPort $ports_a -Action Allow -Protocol TCP";
iex "New-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName 'WSL 2 Firewall Unlock' -Direction Inbound -LocalPort $ports_a -Action Allow -Protocol TCP";

for( $i = 0; $i -lt $ports.length; $i++ ){
  $port = $ports[$i];
  iex "netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=$port listenaddress=$addr";
  iex "netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=$port listenaddress=$addr connectport=$port connectaddress=$remoteport";
}
```

Running this script from an elevated/admin Powershell session did the trick for me. This allows accessing the WSL2 service running on a port to be accessible from the Windows host IP at that same port.

Comment: Worked really well for me -- make sure you have `ifconfig` installed on your WSL2 distro. This can also be added to Task Scheduler on login as `powershell -executionpolicy bypass -f path\to\script.ps1` with a delay of at least 10 seeconds to allow WSL2 to launch first (making your Linux instance available to fetch the machine's IP from).

Comment: It does not help :( Do I need to restart my computer after that or anything?

Comment: @Alexey This worked for me after restarting WSL: `wsl --shutdown`

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/xmeng1/aae4b223e9ccc089911ee764928f5486?permalink_comment_id=4939664#gistcomment-4939664) a version of the script with better error handling and fixes some old mistakes of the author of the script.

Comment: @Seangle author here. Glad to see the solution still being used!

Answer (score 16):

Please follow the steps mentioned in [the link](https://www.nextofwindows.com/allow-server-running-inside-wsl-to-be-accessible-outside-windows-10-host) shared [by erazerbrecht](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835559/access-a-web-server-which-is-running-on-wsl-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-l#comment87265412_49835559) and run your HTTP server by providing your IP address (instead of using [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)) and port number.

Example (as root):

```
cd ~
python3 -m http.server -b 192.168.1.178 8000
```

Output:

```
Serving HTTP on 192.168.1.178 port 8000 (http://192.168.1.178 :8000/) ...
```

Otherwise, you can also do this instead of following [the link](https://www.nextofwindows.com/allow-server-running-inside-wsl-to-be-accessible-outside-windows-10-host):

1. Go to the [Windows Defender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Defender) firewall → *Advanced settings* from the left menu
2. Select *Inbound*
3. Create *New rule*; <kbd>Next</kbd>
4. Select *Program* as a rule type; <kbd>Next</kbd>
5. Select *All Program*; <kbd>Next</kbd>
6. Select *Allow the connection*; <kbd>Next</kbd>
7. Check all three (*Domain*, *Private*, and *Public*); <kbd>Next</kbd>
8. Provide the rule with a name
9. Press <kbd>Finish</kbd>
10. You’re are good to go

Comment: These are the instructions Microsoft provides. Windows firewall is blocking connections exposed by WSL.

Comment: It does work. Ensure you replace IP with your local windows IP. Also while accessing the webpage use IP:PORT to access.

Comment: I can confirm that following all of these instructions does not work. For me viewing my IP at port 8000 shows the document tree of the Windows user profile directory in the browser. The Linux HTTP server does see and log the request however.

Comment: Neither suggestion in this answer worked for me on WSL2. Service can't bind to the Windows IP address because WSL2 has its own network adapter. Same for the firewall. The ports were already working when running the service in Windows, so no use allowing them again.

Comment: @mlibby Have you found the solution? 

Comment: @JohnyL I found one solution, I posted it as an answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66890232/13468

Comment: @mlibby Thank you for your effort. Actually, it was working from the start, but the https protocol error distracted me, and I thought that page isn't reachable. Anyway, thanks for answer!! 

Answer (score 8):

***Avoid*** using firewall rules used in some answers on the web. I saw some of them create some kind of ***allow-all*** firewall rule (allow any traffic from any IP address and any port). This can cause security problems.

Simply use this single line from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70566842/11190169) which worked perfectly for me (it just creates a port proxy):

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=<windows_port> listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=<WSL_port> connectaddress=<WSL_IP>
```

where `<WSL_IP>` is the IP address of [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux). You can get it by running `ifconfig` on WSL. Also `<windows_port>` is the port Windows will listen on and `<wsl_port>` is the port server is running on WSL.

You can list the current port proxies using:

`netsh interface portproxy show all`

Comment: This is helpful in that the single line of Powershell admin is sufficient to reveal the WSL2 port from my WSL2 service to Windows. However for my purposes I needed to make the port available to other machines on my home network, hence I needed to add a firewall rule from the answer you referenced. So long as the service provided isn't sensitive, this shouldn't be an issue if you turn off the public network option, and limit the incoming traffic to private and corporate networks.

Comment: Also, `ip -c a` ought to replace `ifconfig` as the latter is deprecated (and not installed by default).

Answer (score 7):

> it means that I can't connect to this web server from another pc in my network. Is it possible to getting an access to WSL from outside?

It should be noted, among all the answers here, that this question was originally for WSL1 (given when it was asked) and was [self-answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60465289/11810933) by the OP as having been a WSL or Windows issue that was resolved by a Windows update.

Ironically, this is a *known* issue on WSL2 due to the way its networking typically worked (NAT), so years later, people started finding it (and answering it) in that context.

There are *multiple* solutions for this on WSL2. For historical purposes, I'll leave the two older solutions below, but the preferred and officially supported version is now the first listed:

##### WSL2 "Mirrored" Network Mode

As of the September 2023 WSL2 and Windows 11 updates, a new network mode setting is available - *"Mirrored"*. When enabled, this mode will mirror the Windows network interfaces into Linux, enabling (according to the [announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-subsystem-for-linux-september-2023-update/)):

- IPv6 support
- Connect to Windows servers from within Linux using the localhost address 127.0.0.1
- **Connect to WSL directly from your local area network (LAN)**
- Improved networking compatibility for VPNs
- Multicast support

Huzzah!

To enable this mode:

1. Edit the file `.wslconfig` located in your *Windows* user profile directory.  This file does not exist by default.  If you have any questions about making sure you have the correct file, use the following command from PowerShell (as your regular, non-elevated/Admin user):

   ```
   notepad ($env:USERPROFILE+"\.wslconfig")
   ```
2. Ensure the following lines are present:

   ```ini
   [wsl2]
   networkingMode=mirrored
   ```

   Side-note: My understanding is that adding `firewall=false` should allow you to skip some of the next steps, but I've been unable to make that work, so perhaps my understanding is wrong. I'll update if I learn more.  For now ...
3. Exit all running WSL instances
4. From an **elevated, admin** PowerShell, test that the WSL2 firewall is available:

   ```
   Get-NetFirewallHyperVVMCreator
   ```

   If this command returns an empty value, then you may be on an older, unsupported version of Windows, or your WSL needs to be updated (2.0.9.0 or higher is recommended (`wsl --version`)).
5. Assuming you received a value from the previous command, then (still in the elevated, admin PowerShell) either:

   - Easiest (disables WSL2 firewall completely):

     ```
     Set-NetFirewallHyperVVMSetting -Name ((Get-NetFirewallHyperVVMCreator).VMCreatorId) -Enabled False
     ```
   - Safest (allows only traffic from Private networks):

     ```
     New-NetFirewallHyperVRule `
     -DisplayName 'Allow All Inbound Traffic to WSL in Private Network' `
     -Name 'WSL Private Inbound Rule' `
     -Profiles Private `
     -Direction Inbound `
     -Action Allow `
     -VMCreatorId ((Get-NetFirewallHyperVVMCreator).VMCreatorId) `
     -Enabled True
     ```

     Note: To delete this rule, run `Remove-NetFirewallHyperVRule -Name 'WSL Private Inbound Rule'`.

   ^ Credit to [this Github user and comments](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10769#issuecomment-1815884540)
6. Exit the Admin PowerShell session and return to your normal PowerShell:

   ```
   wsl --shutdown
   ```
7. Restart your WSL instance and test using the original command from the question:

   ```
   python3 -m http.server
   ```

   From another device on the local network, you should now be able to access the service using:

   - IPv4 or IPv6: `http://<ip_address>:8000`
   - IPv6 mDNS on a broadcast local network: `http://<windows_system_name>.local:8000`
   - DNS name

---

##### Older solutions

- ***WSL1***: First, just use WSL1.  For *most* (but not all) web development tasks where you need to access your app from another machine on the network, WSL1 will be better at networking and will run your application and tools just fine.  WSL2 brings in real, virtualized Linux kernel, but the "fake kernel" (syscall translation layer) of WSL1 still works fine today for most tasks.

  When running `python3 -m http.server` under WSL1, you'll automatically be able to access it from other machines on the network via the Windows host's IP address (or DNS name).  As the OP mentioned in the self-answer, that pesky WSL1 bug has been fixed for years now.

---

- ***SSH reverse tunnel*** If you do need to use WSL2, here's an option that doesn't require port forwarding or any advanced firewall rules that need to be updated each time WSL restarts.  The problem with those rules is that the IP address for WSL changes every time you restart, meaning those rules have to be deleted and recreated constantly.

  On the other hand, we can use SSH within WSL2 to connect to Windows, where the name, and perhaps even the IP address, is constant.

  ##### One-time setup:  Enable SSH

  There's some one-time setup for this, but it's useful regardless:

  First, install/enable Windows OpenSSH server.  This is a feature that is built-in to Windows and just needs to be enabled.  You'll find the full instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse), but it's typically just a matter of (from an Admin PowerShell):

  ```
  Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
  Start-Service sshd
  Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType 'Automatic'
  if (!(Get-NetFirewallRule -Name "OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object Name, Enabled)) {
      Write-Output "Firewall Rule 'OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP' does not exist, creating it..."
      New-NetFirewallRule -Name 'OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP' -DisplayName 'OpenSSH Server (sshd)' -Enabled True -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -LocalPort 22
  } else {
      Write-Output "Firewall rule 'OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP' has been created and exists."
  }
  ```

  Edit your `C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config` and set `GatewayPorts yes`.  This is what allows us to use SSH as a gateway from other devices on the network.

  Finally, of course, you'll need a firewall rule in Windows allowing the HTTP(s) (or other) port you'll be using.  Example (from Admin PowerShell):

  ```
  New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL Python 8000" -LocalPort 8000 -Action Allow -Protocol TCP
  ```

  And restart the OpenSSH Server service:

  ```
  Restart-Service sshd
  ```

  ##### Create the tunnel

  With that in place, it's a simple matter to create the tunnel we need:

  ```
  ssh -R 8000:localhost:8000 NotTheDr01ds@$(hostname).local
  ```

  <sub>*Replacing, of course, `NotTheDr01ds` with your own Windows username, if it differs from the WSL username*</sub>

  That's going to use your *Windows* username and password since SSH is running on the Windows side.

  Once you have ensured that it works, two other recommendations:

  - Set up key-based authentication so that you don't need to enter a password each time
  - Change the SSH connection to:

    ```
    ssh -fN -R 8000:localhost:8000 NotTheDr01ds@$(hostname).local
    ```

    That will put the SSH session into the background and not allocate a terminal for it.

Comment: Would it be a better idea to use "GatewayPorts clientspecified" instead of "GatewayPorts yes"?

Comment: @solamour Good catch -- Probably.  I haven't tested it thoroughly with that configuration, but I don't see any issues with it at first glance.  Working well for you, I assume?

Comment: In this particular case, "GatewayPorts clientspecified" and "GatewayPorts yes" shouldn't make much difference. Anyhow "SSH reverse tunneling" (ssh from WSL2 to Windows) does work, although I ended up using a plain tunneling (ssh from Windows to WSL2), just to make things simpler on Windows. Thanks for the excellent tip.

Comment: @solamour Right - Now that WSL2 attempts to re-use the same IP address each time, it's easier to go the Windows->WSL route.  I should probably edit that in based on the more recent release since I originally wrote it up.

Comment: I expected WSL2 would get a different IP every time, but so far it has stayed same, even after rebooting Windows. Another option would be creating a bridged network interface in Windows, but that might involve more steps. As for my case, I need it only occasionally, so SSH tunneling is sufficient.

Comment: @solamour Right - It *used* to get a different IP each time, which is why I came up with this reverse tunnel technique.  However, about 6 months or so ago, the WSL team added a feature to have it attempt to use the same IP each time.  With that in place, the "normal tunnel" that you use is now easier than the reverse tunnel that I recommended.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to [countach’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835559/access-a-web-server-which-is-running-on-wsl-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-t/64159675#64159675), but using [iproute2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2):

If using Ubuntu, type `ip address` in the WSL terminal. Look for the entry that says `#: eth0 ...` where `#` is some small number. There is an IP address there. Use that.

Answer (score 6):

For now, (March 2022) to access from outside an application running on WSL 2, we need to do the following:

- Make rules in the firewall for accepting incoming (and maybe also outgoing) connections on the protocol and port on which the application is running (e.g., *TCP/80*)
- Get WSL's VM IP address: `hostname -I`
- As said on this page ([Accessing a WSL 2 distribution from your local area network (LAN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking#accessing-a-wsl-2-distribution-from-your-local-area-network-lan)), use this IP address to add, in Windows, a proxy that listens on the port and redirects to WSL's VM. This is done by the following command in a PowerShell running as administrator:

  ```
  netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=80 connectaddress=192.168.101.100
  ```

Where `192.168.101.100` is the VM's IP address from `hostname -I` and `80` the port we want to open to the outside.

As WSL's IP address changes when rebooted, this should be automated in a PowerShell script, where the previous proxy is removed and a new one is set to the current IP address. All credit goes to Edwindijas on GitHub from who's script this one is heavily inspired:

```
$ports=@(80,21,22) # the ports you want to open
$addr='0.0.0.0';

$wslIP = bash.exe -c "hostname -I"
$found = $wslIP -match '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}';

if(! $wslIP -match '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}') {
  echo "WSL's IP cannot be found. Aborting";
  exit;
}

$portsStr = $ports -join ",";
iex "Remove-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName 'WSL 2 Firewall Unlock' ";
iex "New-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName 'WSL 2 Firewall Unlock' -Direction Outbound -LocalPort $portsStr -Action Allow -Protocol TCP";
iex "New-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName 'WSL 2 Firewall Unlock' -Direction Inbound -LocalPort $portsStr -Action Allow -Protocol TCP";

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $ports.length; $i++) {
  $port = $ports[$i];
  iex "netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=$port listenaddress=$addr";
  iex "netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=$port listenaddress=$addr connectport=$port connectaddress=$wslIP";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Microsoft documentation, *[Accessing Linux networking applications from Windows (localhost)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking#accessing-linux-networking-apps-from-windows-localhost)*:

> According to the docs if you are running an older version of Windows
> (Build 18945 or less), you will need to get the IP address of the
> Linux host VM

This should be a non-issue post the Windows 10 [Build 18945](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2019/07/26/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-18945/) (2019-07-19).

Answer (score 2):

I have written a PowerShell script, using two simple commands which worked perfectly for me.

```
# Get the IP address of the WSL
$str = wsl -- ip -o -4 -json addr list eth0 | ConvertFrom-Json | %{ $_.addr_info.local } | ?{ $_ }
echo "WSL IP address: $str"

# Establish the connection with the WSL
# listenport,connectport ports can be changes as per the needs
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8080 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=8080 connectaddress=$str
```

Create a *.ps1* file using this code and execute it from the PowerShell terminal.
It can be added to [the scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler), so that the script will run every time at Windows boot.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., how does it work? Why does it work? What is it supposed to do? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72993134/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue where I have to access the localhost from my WSL machine (ubuntu)

[image: server running in wsl]

so direct access to the url will not work in your browser as this is a VM but you can imagine it as a machine running on the same local network and access it like that as well, to do that just open a new terminal in ubuntu and run

> ifconfig

if not installed in your wsl just run

> sudo apt install net-tools

there you can see the inet address which can be directly access on your browser

[image: ![broadcast address]

for example in my case I can access the server in my browser by going to

> http://172.23.157.59:8000/

Answer (score 1):

I followed [the answer by @toran-sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51998308/8917310) about adding an inbound rule to Windows Defender Firewall but recently (after adding a 2nd wsl2 instance) it stopped working again. I came across [this issue thread](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4204) and running the following in cmd prompt got it working again for me.

```
wsl --shutdown
```

update: it seems this issue comes from having Fast Startup enabled https://stackoverflow.com/a/66793101/8917310

Comment: To be honest, this question probably wouldn't have been solved by the `wsl --shutdown`.  When it's the Fast Startup issue, that makes even localhost forwarding break, so the original poster wouldn't have been able to the server via `localhost` in Windows.  Since they say that worked, it's unlikely to be the issue you are thinking of.

Comment: `wsl --shutdown` by itself, without adding any firewall rules, actually worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

There's a npm package for that now:

```bash
npx expose-wsl@latest
```

Comment: This works, but I'm struggling to understand what the exact problem is --- Every proposed solution I've seen doesn't work --- But this does.

Answer (score -3):

I've tested on **Update for Microsoft Windows (KB4532132)** with a reinstalled WSL, and it works as expected.

It seems the issue was related to an old Windows version or old WSL version.