# How to access localhost on another pc

Tags: webserver, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I’m a developer and in my day to day, I need to access my application locally. The famous localhost:3000.

But when I used Manjaro, it was possible to access my localhost on another pc through the same network.

For example pc-ip/3000. Now I needed to use Windows with Arch WSL and I can no longer access my localhost on another pc. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Assuming your application is listening on all interfaces and not only 127.0.0.1 you should still be able to access it from other PCs on the same LAN using the private local IP address (192.168., 10.0... etc). This sounds like it could just be a firewall issue and you need to open up port 3000 in the windows firewall for all profiles. Or maybe set the LAN connection as a private rather than public network.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  See the question [Access a web server which is running on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) from local network](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49835559/11810933) -- There are multiple options there for how to configure this.  The easiest, IMHO, is to [use WSL1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73690504/11810933) as I mention in my answer there.  But if that's not possible, I'm partial to the SSH technique I mention as well.  Let me know if that doesn't work for you.