# How do I diagnose problems with access to Apache server running on WSL from within the same home network?

Tags: apache, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**Overview**

I am trying to set up an Apache webserver on a Windows 11 machine running Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on my home computer. Using the IP address returned for eth0 by `ip a` in a WSL shell, say 172.26.xx.xx, I can access my simple web page from the same computer. However, I cannot access the page from another computer in the same network.

**Details**

My ports.conf file, located at `/etc/apache2`, contains the following, in addition to a few comments:

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Stripped of comments, my apache2.conf file, located at `/etc/apache2`, contains

```
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

My 000-default.conf file, located at /etc/apache2/sites-available, contains

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAdmin example@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html>
           AllowOverride All
           Options All
           Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

For what's worth, I do have a registered domain which I use to instead of *example.com* above. (Because I am behind a home router without a static IP address, I used ddclient to setup a dynamic DNS with my provider. This seems to be working, insofar as the same IP address is shown for my network by https://whatismyipaddress.com/ and in the automatically populated field in the management page of my DNS registrar. However, unless I completely misunderstand things, this is irrelevant, because I cannot access my page from another computer even *within* the same network.)

**What I have tried**

Honestly, not much. The configuration of the Apache server seemed to me pretty straightforward, and for connections from the same computer it run right away. The only things I could think of were

*Port forwarding issues.*

Running `sudo ufw status verbose` on the WSL shell returns

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                            Action      From
--                            ------      ----
22/tcp                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80/tcp                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443                           ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80,443/tcp (Apache Full)      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80,443/tcp (Apache Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

which looks fine with me. Following instructions from [here](https://aalonso.dev/blog/accessing-network-apps-running-inside-wsl2-from-other-devices-in-your-lan-1e1p), I ran `netsh interface portproxy` to map ports 80 and 443 on the Windows computer to ports 80 and 443 on WSL. The key commands in the script are

```
netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=$port listenaddress=$addr"
```

and

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=$port listenaddress=$addr connectport=$port connectaddress=$remoteport
```

with `$remoteport` matching the IP address 172.26.xx.xx returned by `ip a` and `$addr` left as 0.0.0.0.

I have also created an inbound rule in Windows Defender Firewall, following the instructions at https://www.nextofwindows.com/allow-server-running-inside-wsl-to-be-accessible-outside-windows-10-host, but I believe those are superseded in WSL2 by the instructions above. Both of these potential solutions have been discussed at [Access a web server which is running on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) from the local network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835559/access-a-web-server-which-is-running-on-wsl-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-t), but neither one nor any other suggestion in the question worked for me.

I don't know whether this port forwarding was truly necessary, or how to diagnose whether it did what it was supposed to do. In any case, I ran `netstat -aobn | findstr :80` in a priviledged Powershell session from Windows, which returned

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5720
TCP    10.0.0.229:56431       10.0.0.249:8009        ESTABLISHED     11868
TCP    10.5.0.2:54444         192.229.211.108:80     CLOSE_WAIT      22772
TCP    [::1]:80               [::]:0                 LISTENING       9280
```

as well `Get-NetTCPConnection | where localport -eq 80`, which returned, edited for compactness,

```
LocalAddress LocalPort RemoteAddress RemotePort State  AppliedSetting OwningProcess
------------ --------- ------------- ---------- -----  -------------- -------------
::1          80        ::            0          Listen                9280
0.0.0.0      80        0.0.0.0       0          Listen                5720
```

Does anyone see anything interesting there?

*Investigating logs.*

In /var/logs/apache2/error.log there are many groups just like

```
[Sun Oct 15 18:37:05.433219 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 19762:tid 139729704814464] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Sun Oct 15 18:37:05.441983 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 19762:tid 139729704814464] AH00489: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Oct 15 18:37:05.441995 2023] [core:notice] [pid 19762:tid 139729704814464] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

and nothing else, but these match the many times in which I ran `sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf`, `sudo systemctl reload apache2`, `sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf`, and `sudo systemctl reload apache2` in this order after a change.

Here are other configuration parameters, in the unlikely case it matters:

- Desktop running 11 version 23H2 build 25967.1010.
- WSL version 2.0.3.0
- Ubuntu 22.04.03, kernel version 5.15.123.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
- Apache Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)

My question is how I diagnose the problem, as this is a learning experience for me, but a straight up solution is welcome too, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original issue may have been related to running the server in WSL. The evidence for that is that I do not have problems when running a server on a dedicated Linux machine. I have given up on my original approach and followed this new approach instead.