# How to expose port in WSL to the LAN?

Tags: web, port, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to expose a web service running on the WSL to my LAN that I can access from another computer.
For example:

```
python -m http.server
```

I can access on my Windows via "0.0.0.0:8000" but can not access from the ip address "192.168.1.108:8000"

p.s. in the `.wslconfig` I set `networkMode=mirrored`

I've tried this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835559/access-a-web-server-which-is-running-on-wsl-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-t)

But the methods of installing expose-wsl or modifing Firewall's inbound rules or using `netsh` command all don't work...

Comment: I don't think this is a WSL problem, but you need to [`--bind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) the server to that IP (instead of the default localhost)

Comment: @Bergi No, I've tried that. I use the command `python -m http.server -bind 192.168.1.108 8000` But still can not access it via the ip address

Comment: It's `--bind` not `-bind`?

Comment: I would have expected `--bind 0.0.0.0` (listen on any interface), but I guess the specific IP should work as well. Also I'm surprised you visited http://0.0.0.0:8000/, not [the loopback address](https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0) http://127.0.0.1:8000/ (or http://localhost:8000/)