# What do I need to do on Windows 11 to access WSL2 nodejs app from another computer on my local network?

Tags: wsl-2

I just upgraded to Windows 11 and have been using WSL2 (previously I was using git bash and running the app directly on Windows 10). The app is running great on the Win11 machine, I can develop as normal and access the WSL2 app on localhost:3000.

I'm developing a PWA and have an Android / iPhone on the local network that I was using for development and testing by accessing 192.168.2.104:3000 where that is my Win11 machine local IP address and the phones are also on the same network.

I didn't change any settings on the Windows 10 environment that I'm aware of, my phones were just able to see the app and use it just fine. In Win11 / WSL2 I can't seem to connect from another device.

I've tried changing my Network configuration to categorize as a Private network, I noticed that it's set to notify me when Windows Firewall blocks a new app but I'm not seeing anything about it being blocked.

I'm assuming this may be something simple, but other questions I've seen on here seem to be about configuring local Win11 -> WSL2 connections which was just working out of the box for me. Specifically I haven't seen anything about this specific setup. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access a web server which is running on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) from the local network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835559/access-a-web-server-which-is-running-on-wsl-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-t) - I'm partial to my answer on that question, of course ;-).  You aren't missing anything - It's not "simple", unfortunately, but a side-effect of the way that WSL2 networking is handled.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that my answer (and all of the others as well) may be out-of-date.  There's a new feature that should help with this.  I'll do a bit of testing on it, and post an update to that answer soon.  I'll ping you with a reply here when it's ready.

Comment: Patrick - My answer listed above is now updated with how to use new "mirror" networking Mode, assuming you are on the latest releases of Windows and WSL.  Sorry for the delay - Took a little more work and testing than I expected.